# Is it true if $\dim N(A-\lambda_i) = AM(\lambda_i)$ then the matrix is always diagonalizable?

Tags: linear-algebra

Imagine we look at a matrix A with the following characteristic polynomials:

$ \phi_A = (\lambda - 1) ^n$

So it has algebraic multiplicity of n. Only if there are $n$ corresponding eigenvectors associated with this eigenvalue, the matrix $A$ is diagonalizable.

What happens if we get the following characteristic polynomials?

$ \phi_A = (\lambda - 1) ^r (\lambda - 2)^k $, $r+k = n$

$ \phi_A = (\lambda - 1) ^r (\lambda - 2)^k (\lambda - 3)^l $, $r+k+l = n$

So in this case the matrix is only diagonalisable if the $\dim N(A-\lambda_i) = m(\lambda_i)$, where $m(\lambda_i)$ represents the algebraic multiplicity.

$\phi_A = (\lambda -1)(\lambda -2)(\lambda -3)(\lambda -4) .... (\lambda -n)$

The last one it is clear that the algebraic multiplicity and geometric multiplicity are equal.
So this matrix must be diagonalizable.

Question:

So is this reasoning right? Is it true if $\dim N(A-\lambda_i) = AM(\lambda_i)$ then the matrix is always diagonalizable?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, the statement and your reasoning are correct.